# Calculations in if statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I want to perform a simple calculation with the Field Calculator using this piece of script (note that all the elif statements are attempts for another syntax and non of the worked):

```
def change(OldFor_Com):
    if (OldFor_Com) == "OHWH":
        return shape.area@Hectares / 40
    elif (OldFor_Com) == "OHWH":
        return !shape.area@Hectares / 30!
    elif (OldFor_Com) == "OHWH":
        return (!shape.area@Hectares / 30!)
    elif (OldFor_Com) == "OHWH":
        return !shape.area@Hectares! / 30
    elif (OldFor_Com) == "OHWH":
        return (!shape.area@Hectares! / 30)
    if (OldFor_Com == "OTHH"):
        return !shape.area@hectares! / 40
```

If the field is populated with `OTHH` I want another field to be populated with the area of the field, divided by 40, or 30, or... and so on.
I modified my syntax a couple of times (as you can see) but it still says `Invalid Syntax`.

Is a calculation possible with these if statement or do I need a workaround?

**Note** that the shape.area@Hectares is an expression to calculate the area of the field, and not another field in my attributetable!

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

[image: screen3]

[image: screen3]

**EDIT:** 7/15/2014 around 11pm

I modified the script. I added a field to the table and calculate the area of the shape first (with !shape.area@Hectares!) and then I try to run this

```
def change(OldFor_Com):
    if OldFor_Com == "OTHH":
        return Area_Ha / 40
    if OldFor_Com == "OHWH":
        return Area_Ha / 30
    if OldFor_Com == "OSFH":
        return Area_Ha / 375
    if OldFor_Com == "PINE":
        return Area_Ha / 10
    if OldFor_Com == "OOFH":
        return Area_Ha / 375
    if OldFor_Com == "None":
        return Area_Ha
    else:
        return 0
```

It bounces back with the following:

```
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: change(u"OTHH", 7) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: change() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Failed to execute (Calculate Field (10)).
```

Is it not possible to do any calculations in the if statement?

**EDIT:** 7/15/14 12:30pm

This how the attributestable looks like before I add the field `SizeScore`

[image: before]

After I add the field `SizeScore` (FLOAT).

[image: after]

And the following screen comes up if I use this code:

```
def change(OldFor_Com, Area_Ha):
    if OldFor_Com == "OTHH":
        x = Area_Ha / 40
        return x
    if OldFor_Com == "OHWH":
        x =  Area_Ha / 30
        return x
    if OldFor_Com == "OOFH":
        x = Area_Ha / 375
        return x
    if OldFor_Com == "OSFH":
        x = Area_Ha / 375
        return x
    if OldFor_Com == "PINE":
        x =  Area_Ha / 10
        return x
    if OldFor_Com == "None":
        return Area_Ha
    else:
        return 0
```

[image: screen]

It only populates the rows where it does not need to calculate. 
The only statement that is working is that one.

```
if OldFor_Com == "None":
     return Area_Ha
```

But for the others are no error messages coming back!

**SOLVED, SEE ACCEPTED ANSWERE** 
Thanks a lot to everybody who went through this with me!

Comment: I don't believe you can mix/match 4 and 2 spaces. Stick with one or the other.

Comment: If I add four spaces (not six) to the third line it says intendent error. If I add six or eight it says error in the syntax. I did this intendation (four and six) in other calculations before and it worked fine.

Comment: Try multiples of 2 or multiples of 4. First indent block is 2, then 4, then 6, etc. OR it should be 4 -> 8 -> 12 -> etc. See [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/00170000004s000000/), first bullet point under Note.

Comment: @ Paul thanks for the link. I will keep this in mind. There is still a mistake in the Syntax though.

Comment: What's in your parser? And what is the field type? Is it a shapefile, SDE? etc.

Comment: Python 9_3, the Fieldtype is FLOAT and the input is a shapefile. I attach a screen in a sec.

Comment: Are there any fields where `OldFor_Com` is not `"OHWH"` or `"OTHH"`? If so, you need an `else: return 0 # or some other value` to make sure there's a return value for every row.

Comment: Also, make sure you aren't mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. Even if they *look* the same, they are most assuredly not.

Comment: @nm peterson: Yes there are. I want to do to this fields exactly the same what I am doing to `OHWH` and `OTHH`, but with different calculations. But will I get a Syntax error if I am not defining them?

Comment: See my latest edit & comments. Tested and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your newest updates to the question, this should work:

```
def change(OldFor_Com, Area_Ha):
    if OldFor_Com == "OTHH":
        return Area_Ha / 40.0
    elif OldFor_Com == "OHWH":
        return Area_Ha / 30.0
    elif OldFor_Com == "OOFH":
        return Area_Ha / 375.0
    elif OldFor_Com == "OSFH":
        return Area_Ha / 375.0
    elif OldFor_Com == "PINE":
        return Area_Ha / 10.0
    elif OldFor_Com == "None":
        return Area_Ha
    else:
        return 0
```

The reason you were seeing all `0`s (except for the "None" case) was not that the function wasn't working, but rather that you were dividing integers by integers. The results were always less than 1, and Python always rounds *down* for integer math. Adding `.0` to each of the denominators forces decimal math, and the results will be decimals.

(Alternatively -- and this is probably better -- is to make the "Area_Ha" field a float/double instead of an integer. Then your function would work exactly as you've written it.)

Comment: Awesome dude. Thats working now! Thanks a lot for the explanation! Now I am a little bit more pythionic again :) Till he next problem which is probably just waiting around the corner. Could you explain why I need the variable x though?

Comment: You don't, I added that in there to see what was going on in the original cod. it should work if you take out the x and just use `return area / 10.0`

Comment: Yeah, you don't need an intermediate variable. I cleaned up the code in the answer and added the `elif`s back in to make the code more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send your area field into your calculation as a parameter.

Expression:  `change(!OldFor_Com!, !shape.area@hectares!)`

Code Block:

```
def change(OldFor_Com, area):
    if OldFor_Com == "OTHH":
        return area / 40
    elif OldFor_Com == "OHWH":
        return area / 30
```

Comment: The setting of the `!` I tried in my third `elif` statement. Does not work.

Comment: Is the invalid syntax being reported before the third line?  If so, the calculation never gets there to attempt that syntax.

Comment: Edit my question. With this syntax I added to the post the error is in the third line.

Comment: I updated the indentation, looks like I was off by one.

Comment: The intendation is fine. I get a different error message if the intendation is wrong. It is still the syntax

Comment: @evv_gis not sure why you reversed my edit. If you put `!shape.area@hectares!` in the expression directly, there's no need to calculate a separate "area_hect" field using that very expression...

Comment: @nmpeterson when I tried that, I received an error stating the field did not exist. Perhaps I fat-fingered something.

Answer (score 1):

Your exclamation marks need to be wrapped around the field name:

```
def change(OldFor_Com):
    if OldFor_Com == "OTHH":
       return !shape.area@Hectares! / 40
    elif OldFor_Com == "OHWH":
       return !shape.area@Hectares! / 30
```

Also, make sure Python is the defined Parser.

Comment: Thats what I tried in my third `elif` statement. Does not work. Python is defined as parser.

Comment: Updated, removed some unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: @artwork21 you only need one if statement for "OHWH" as well. I think OP was just testing multiple formattings to see if it would work.

Comment: Yep GISKid, that what I did

Comment: I see, was not sure if those were place holders to be updated later.

Comment: @Stophface, Also make sure the field you are calculating on is type float or double.

Comment: @artwork21 it is. But even if not, that shpuld not come up as a syntaxerror right?

Comment: I believe the issue here is you said you want to update a second field, yet in your python definition you only reference one

Comment: **In the python code block the !shape.area! is out of scope** this is a very common misconception. See this page http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004s000000 for explanation. The exclamation marks go in the expression not the code block. **the answer by @ew_gis is correct** except the expression should be change(OldFor_Com!, !shape.area@Hectares!)

Answer (score 0):

Going off of your latest edit and ew_GIS try this:

Expression: `change(!OldFor_Com!, !Area_Ha!)`

Code Block:

```
def change(OldFor_Com, area):
  if OldFor_Com == "OTHH":
     return area / 40
  elif OldFor_Com == "OHWH":
     return area / 30
  elif OldFor_Com in ("OOFH", "OSFH", "OOFH"):
    return area / 375
  elif OldFor_Com == "PINE":
    return  area / 10
  elif OldFor_Com == "None":
    return area
  else:
    return 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I edited my post! The `OR` statement does not work, Field Calculator does not like the syntax so I made it an extra `elif` argument.

Comment: Strange, could you try running it as a stand-alone script instead of in the field calculator? I'm out of touch with ArcGIS 9.3. It's been some time.

Comment: It should work in the Field Calculator shouldnt it?
I could try running it as a standalone script but it needs to be included in the modelbuilder.
Its ArcGis 10.2 I am working with

Comment: `OR` does not work because it should be `or`. Alternatively, use `elif OldFor_Com in ("OSFH", "OOFH"):`

Comment: Thanks Paul! I'm still a rookie
@Stophface See my edit, I just tested it and it worked.

Comment: @ GISKid. Thanks for the update. I copied and pasted it into the field calculator but it does not work. Its just updating the `None` values. I tried it with `Area_Ha` instead of `area` (because the values from the rows in `Area_Ha` need to be divided by the certain numbers, i.e. 40, 375, etc., thats what we define here `change(!OldFor_Com!, !Area_Ha!)`) But that did not work. You said it worked for you? Did you run it as a `standalone script` or in the `fieldcalculator`?

Comment: I ran it in field calculator. It doesn't really matter what the variable after change(x,y) is because you're basically saying y = !Area_Ha! in the expression. My OldFor_Com was string, Area_ha float and SizeScore also float. Did you get a specific error?